# Software update KB3136000 has not been installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, certificate, .net-framework

I'd like to install manually `.Net FrameWork 4.6.1` security update that releases most recently.

When I try to install that update I gave this error:

Software update kb3136000 has not been installed because:
A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

After I googled this error I found this: [A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2016/03/28/a-certificate-chain-could-not-be-built-to-a-trusted-root-authority-2/), however, when I used the `Certmgr.exe` command in `Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio` I got this error:
`Certmgr.exe` is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft released a document on this issue...https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3149737

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I downloaded this [certificate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2016/03/28/a-certificate-chain-could-not-be-built-to-a-trusted-root-authority-2/) and doubled click on it and try to install it to `Trusted Root` using wizard.
After that, I could run that update (KB3136000).